# Redirect on php include increase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but.

If I have a php file I'm calling like so

```
<?php include 'number.php';?>
```

which is a number that will increase every hour or two.

- How can I actively check if the number has changed?
- When the number increases how can I trigger a sound alert followed by a redirect?

What I'm currently doing is using a "refresh every 5 seconds" within *number.php*

```
<body onload="setInterval(function() {window.location.reload();}, 5000);">
```

Then I'm trying to use jquery to console log the number and check for increased values, but I realized that it wasn't going to happen so I will spare you the messy code.

This is what I'm trying to trigger:

```
$("#alert").get(0).play();    
$(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Any solution is fine. Also I'm starting to think an iframe is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Declare the var
    var num = 0;

    // Function to be called every 5 secs
    var update = function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/number.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (output) {
            return output;
        }
      });
    };

    // Every 5 secs call update(), check if return a number > 0, and add it to num var
    setInterval(function () {
        var out = update();
        if (out > 0) {
            num += out;
        }
        console.log(num);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Well you've got me on the right direction to figuring it out for myself so I appreciate your help. I'm currently at the stage of appending the numbers to the page (every 5 seconds), now I need to figure out how to check to see if the number has increased and Do .this IF it has.